# 3G mode instead of LTE after switching back from Super Saving Mode

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-s7, samsung-galaxy-s-7-edge

I've seen this for a long time and able to reproduce it on my phone

1) In `normal` mode, use `LTE` network mode

2) Switch to `Super Power Saving` mode

3) Switch back to `normal` mode

After switching back to normal node, the connection type is changed to `3G/2G (auto connect)` rather than `LTE/3G/2G (auto connect)`. So basically I should manually select `LTE`. Is there a workaround this issue?

My model is `SM-G935F`
My software version is Android `6.0.1`, `G935FXXU1BPJJ`

Thanks

Comment: [Smart Network](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ma.wanam.smartnetwork) may help. Requires root and xposed

Comment: @beeshyams I think it's not available in the US at the moment, plus I wouldn't root my phone just for that. But thank you anyways! I hope it will be fixed in latest firmware versions.